# JWT or AWT for DocuSign integration

Tags: docusignapi

I am building an application that will be used by end users in multiple organizations to create and send envelopes for signatures. I am trying to figure out the correct authorization workflow. For this example, say I am manish@example.com.

My understanding of JWT is that JWT will impersonate manish@example.com when any of these 1000's of end users in different organizations send envelopes. Is that correct? But if so, won't they need to authorize the app to impersonate me when they first try to create an envelope? How will these users get my credentials? Would I have to share my credentials with all these end users of my application? Can they log in with their own credentials instead? But if my application is impersonating my own credentials to send envelopes on behalf of these end users, why do I need permission from these users to use my own credentials? After all, in the JWT workflow, the redirect URL does not return any information about the identity of these users of my application.

So, if my app impersonates me, how do end users get my credentials? And, if my app impersonates me, why can't I give this permission to the app once and for all at the time of creating the app? Why do end users have to permit me to impersonate myself?

On a related note, JWT is working great when I use my own personal DocuSign API credentials to authorize my app in testing. But when I try to use my own organization credentials to authorize the app, I get the following error. I also get this error when I try the AWT workflow. How can I fix this error:

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50105: The signed in user 'manish@test.edu' is not assigned to a role for the application '225d2ddd-e3a3-4bed-a310-8a9b8786363e'(Docusign Test).
```

Help in setting up the correct authorization workflow would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT enables developers to request a token on behalf of some user without that user having to log in.
That means that except for the first time when the user have to consent - there's no web UI required to obtain a token.
JWT tokens are for a specific user in a specific account and it's the GUID of that userID that is used to uniquely identify a user. If you have multiple accounts - you will have to ensure you use the right userID for the right user for the right account.
Note also that users in DocuSign have different permissions profiles and may or may not have the access required to do what the API is trying to do.

Finally, clarifying one last thing, you wrote :

> when any of these 1000's of end users in different organizations send

If you have thousands of end users that will be **sending** envelope (not just signing them) then JWT is probably not the best choice for you. You can still use it, but you will need some way to know the userId of the user which means you'll need some uber-auth JWT user that is used first or keep tables of users (I assume users can be added/removed etc.) it's not an ideal way to do things.

Comment: Thanks, to clarify - right now, when I make changes to the app and run it to test the app, every now and then it asks me to log in to my account. This is why I'm worried that our end users may be asked to log in using my credentials, because right now, I've hard-coded my client id as the impersonated user id. But from your response, can I take it that once the app is deployed, I can just run it, authorize the app once, and then let it run for weeks without any end user being asked to log in? This will be great. We can figure out other authorization methods once we have something that works.

Comment: you are asked to log into your account when you do what? 
Note that when you used embedded features, this will not happen, but I'm not clear exactly what your app does.

Comment: Thanks. My app is currently based on eg002 in the Quickstart - SigningViaEmailController. There is no embedded feature. I am just testing sending by email. But the following sometimes asks for login:
    DocuSignAuthUrl = AuthorizationEndpoint + "?response_type=code" +
                            "&scope=" + jwt_scopes +
                            "&client_id=" + ClientId +
                            "&redirect_uri=" + AppUrl + "/home/senddocumentforsigning?authType=JWT";

            return Redirect(DocuSignAuthUrl);

Comment: this is login for the purpose of consent. It's not "sometimes" it's very accurate. It is done if you do not have consent for the app+user combination. Consent is needed only once, per app, per user. ever. Unless you revoke it. This is the only reason you are asked to log in. There's an option to use administrative consent and that would be org-wide.

Comment: One other related issue. Multiple times, I have started development on a new day, and I get the error message such as - "the URI is not configured properly." I just have to log in to my DocuSign API dashboard and try again, and the error goes away. No edits to the configuration, just logging in to the API account. Is there an error in my application?

Comment: "the URI is not configured properly." error is coming from where? maybe you can include a screenshot or explain where in the code and who is sending this error?